React | ES module scope error during npm run start
I am using Vite + React typescript for my UI project and deploying it from a nodeJS server. Suddenly getting this error post build while trying to run the app.
Tried couple of solutions, nothing seem to work
Could someone provide inputs on how to resolve this?
using workspace styled repo, so the build will happen from main package.json at root level
UI tsconfig.json
{"$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",

  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Language & Environment */
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": ["ES6", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Modules */
    "module": "ES6",
    "types": ["jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },

    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,

    /* Interop Constraints */
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    /* Emit */
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },

  "include": [".eslintrc.js", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.cjs", "**/*.mjs"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],

  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]}

UI tsconfig.node.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}

UI package.json
{
  "name": "",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build && npm run build:module",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix src --ext ts,tsx",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build:module": "npm run build:tailwindcss && webpack --config webpack-module.config.js",
    "build:tailwindcss":"tailwindcss -o ./src/tailwind.css --minify"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 16.20.0",
    "npm": ">= 8.19.4"
  }
}

Backend tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "./target/",
    "rootDirs": ["./src"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"],
    "lib": ["DOM"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "exclude": ["toolbox", "dist", "target", "__mocks__", "src/**/*.test.ts"],
  "include": ["./src"]
}

backend package JSON
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "",
  "main": "server.ts",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 16.20.0",
    "npm": ">= 8.19.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config ./server.js dotenv_config_path=/etc/secrets/.env",
    "start:local": "node -r dotenv/config ./server.js",
    "test": "tap",
    "dev": "npm run build && node -r dotenv/config ./target/server.js"
  },
  "tap": {
    "coverage-map": "coverage_map.ts",
    "coverage-report": "json",
    "ts": true
  }
}

file:///opt/app/server.js:38
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
                      ^
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/opt/app/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
